# Output Custom Category Fields on a Zoo Triggers Listing

Tags: expressionengine

I have a Structure-based site with category listing pages. For example: http://www.mysite.com/products/category/tools/hammers. Naturally, I'm using [Zoo Triggers](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-triggers) to output the entry listing.

My problem is that each category listing page needs unique SEO meta data, so I set up custom fields for Title, Keywords, and Description. Unfortunately, Zoo Triggers doesn't have variables for custom category fields, and the `{exp:channel:category_heading}` tag won't work on Zoo Triggers URLs.

I thought I could use the magical [GWCode Categories plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories), but I can't figure out how to display data for the current category only.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can make this happen? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably calls for a custom query. As EE stores its core and custom category data in separate tables this is a bit unwieldy for the native query module, so I'd be inclined to use Rob Sanchez's [ActiveRecord plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/activerecord). I haven't tested this extensively but the following snippet should be in the ballpark:

```
{exp:activerecord
    select="d.field_id_1 as seo_field_one, d.field_id_2 as seo_field_two"
    from="category_field_data as d"
    join="categories as c"
    on="c.cat_id = d.cat_id"
    where[a]="c.cat_url_title = '{triggers:last_segment}'"
    where[b]="c.group_id = '1'"
}
    <p>Field one: {seo_field_one}</p>
    <p>Field two: {seo_field_two}</p>
{/exp:activerecord}
```

If you're not particularly familiar with CodeIgniter's Active Record class, this is doing the following:

- Selecting your custom category fields based on their column names, e.g. `field_id_1`, and creating aliases for use within your template, e.g. `{seo_field_one}`.
- Creating a join between the `categories` and `category_field_data` tables so that we can retrieve data in the field_data table based on values in the categories table.
- Restricting the results set to categories whose URL title matches the last URL segment and who belong to category group 1.

In order to implement this in your template you'd need to adjust the select statement so that it's retrieving data from the right columns and tweak the `group_id` to match up with your category group. I'm assuming that you want to retrieve data for the last URL segment but you can easily adjust that too if need be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dom! How is using the ActiveRecord plugin different from the Query module?

Comment: The ActiveRecord plugin, since it uses CI ActiveRecord on the back end, escapes string data before passing it in; the Query module does NOT, which makes it much less safe for any data that your users can influence (like segment data, etc.)

Plus some people think it's easier. :) But the big argument in favor is the escaping of strings.

Comment: Yep, that about covers it. Also, once you've spent time coding CI apps/EE addons the Active Record class becomes second nature, so it seems only logical to carry that through to any queries in templates. For me it also feels 'neater' and arguably simplifies writing queries a little too. It's a better option in almost every respect.

Comment: @DomStubbs Works great Dom, thanks! I edited your answer to add the `triggers:` prefix before the `last_segment` variable, but it hasn't been approved yet.
@adrienne I think I read that the ActiveRecord plugin is faster than the Query module too, is that correct?

Comment: @kgrote I think it depends a lot on the actual query involved. Active Record, like all ORMs and proto-ORMs, is a pretty leaky abstraction, but it is pretty fast for small and simple queries. It's honestly just hard to say.

Comment: @kgrote Glad to hear it worked. I'm not familiar with Zoo Triggers but `{last_segment}` should normally work on its own as it's a [core global variable](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/url_segments.html#last-segment). Does ZT do something that changes that? As far as performance is concerned I doubt you'd see a noticeable difference compared to the query module, particularly with a simple query like this. The AR plugin is probably technically a tiny bit slower as it a) builds the query for you and b) runs values through `xss_clean()`.

Comment: @DomStubbs Zoo Triggers kind of works like [Freebie](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freebie), where any segments after the category trigger word are ignored by EE so ZT can create an accurate category listing. So you have to use variables prefixed with `triggers:` to get a correct value. That's what lead to my original problem, because EE doesn't recognize ZT segments, so it doesn't know how to return custom category fields with the `exp:channel:category_heading` tag.

Comment: @kgrote Ah, got it, thanks. I've added the `triggers:` prefix to my sample code.